# Why does A* algorithm find the an optimal path without visiting all the nodes?

Tags: algorithm, path-finding

I understand that if a heuristic is admissible, A* does not to visit every node to find the most optimal path. Looking at visualizations of each algorithm, A* stops as soon as it reaches its goal node. So how are you sure that your path is the most optimal one if you haven't explored all possible paths to the goal node? How does overestimating each cost path ensure the optimal solution?

Comment: I think you have it backwards. An admissible heuristic _never_ overestimates the cost of a path from a given node to a goal node. A* works because when it visits a goal node, it knows that the cost from any other visited node to a goal is _at least_ as much as the cost to the goal node being visited.

Comment: @TedHopp is exactly right. A less precise intuitive way to think about it is that the heuristic value is an upper bound on the length of an optimal path to the goal, proceeding from the current search node. This upper bound lets the search avoid "dumb moves" that would necessarily produce longer paths. It avoids them simply because they must be too far back in the open list to ever make it to the head.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider Dijkstra algorithm, that is a special case of A* in which the heuristic is always 0. Dijkstra visits nodes in order of shortest distance from the source, and as such the moment it visits the target node, you know it's the shortest path, since all the unvisited nodes are strictly further away, so going through them can't possibly yield a shorter path.

Now in A* you visit nodes in order of their distances from source plus the value of the heuristic. We assume that the value of the heuristic for a given node doesn't exceed the shortest distance from that node to the target. When you visit the target for the first time, let's call the distance from the source to the target at that moment is `d_t`. Consider any node `v` you haven't visited yet. You know that the distance from the source to that node `d_v` plus the value of the heuristic `h_v` is larger than `d_t` (because you visit nodes in the order of that value, so all unvisited nodes have that value larger). Also note that the shortest distance from `v` to `t` is larger than or equal to `h_v` by the assumption we made above. From that it follows that the distance from source to target through `v` will be longer than `d_t`, so there's no reason to consider that node. Thus `d_t` is the shortest path from source to target.